# Create list copy of distinct objects

Tags: python, list, object, duplicates

If a have a list of objects

```
for i in range(0,10):
 listA.append(foo(i))
```

How can I duplicate `listA` into `listB` such that the objects have the same properties but the objects in each list are **not** the same object. Such that if I do

```
listA[5].bar = 1
```

This does not modify the value of `listB[5].bar`

My aim is to generate multiple copies of an initial list of objects and be able to operate on each lists objects as it's their own instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform the desired action using `deepcopy`.

Here's an example:

```
import copy

listA = [1,2,3,4]
listB = copy.deepcopy(listA)

listB[0] = 7

print("List A: {}".format(listA)) # List A: [1,2,3,4]
print("List B: {}".format(listB)) # List B: [7,2,3,4]
```

This will create an entirely new list `listB` with the same values as `listA`.

When performing a simple assignment, such as:

```
listA = [1,2,3,4]
listB = listA
print(listA is listB) # True
```

this will print `True` as the `listA` and `listB` refer to the same object.

A `deepcopy` will create a new object:

```
import copy

listA = [1,2,3,4]
listB = copy.deepcopy(listA)
print(listA is listB) # False
```

Alternatively, you can create a new list using the `list` constructor.

```
listA = [1,2,3,4]
listB = list(listA)
print(listA is listB) # False
```